# Adding column to df: Error in `$<-.data.frame: replacement has x rows, data has 153

Tags: r, missing-data

I receive an error when I try to add a column to my dataframe from a regression:

```
df <- airquality
ozone.ols <- lm(Ozone ~ Temp, data = df)
df$residuals <- ozone.ols$residuals
```

It returns the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, resi, value = c(`1` = 25.2723695469062,  : 
  replacement has 116 rows, data has 153
```

I guess the problems is missing values? How do I overcome this?

My end-goal is to produce a residual plot following [this](https://rpubs.com/cyobero/187387) guide. Thus, after the code above the plot is produced:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(y = residuals, x = Temp)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed correctly that the problem is that `lm` removes the missing values, so the result vector is the wrong length and R doesn't know how to add it back into the data frame.

You have few options:
(1) use a modelling function that can live with missing variables such as `xgboost`
(2) impute a value for the missing data
(3) leave the model as is, but then the predictions are undefined where there is missing data.

(1) and (2) you could write a whole book about, but to achieve (3) you can do the following:

```
df$result <- NA ## actually, this line is not necessary
df$result[complete.cases(df[,c("Ozone","Temp")])] <- ozone.ols$residuals
```

Comment: @markhogue only if the `result` column already exists: you can't assign into a subset of a column that does not yet exist.

Comment: just realised an embarrassing mistake — adding in the `NA` column means there won't be any complete cases! Have updated answer to only check the input columns.

Comment: Thanks. However, I guess the `NA` assignment isn't needed. After resetting R, I ran both `df$residuals[complete.cases(df)] <- ozone.ols$residuals` and `df$result[complete.cases(df[,c("Ozone","Temp")])] <- ozone.ols$residuals` right after the lm-function. The columns Results and Residuals turn out equal.

Comment: guess I learned something then :) I'm sure this used to be disallowed, perhaps it changed in some R version and I missed the memo. But you are quite right, it does work with modern R.